# How to colourise a range of cells based on a start & end date?

Tags: google-sheets

Can this be achieved by Google Sheets conditional formatting feature?

[image]

Comment: If you had dates above `MTWTFSS` as headers, It would be easier(the row data header need not be visible).

Comment: I think that should be possible to add them. How would that change it?

Answer (score 2):

Just type in a function yielding a number for each cell colour you want to use, and set the text colour to none, like:

```
=($D14<=M$3)*(M$3<=$E14)
```

This will yield 1 if the date on line 3 is between those of columns D and E, and zero otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

Create a demo sheet.

A2(start date): `2018-06-23`
B2(end date): `2018-06-26`

C1:I1

```
 2018-06-23 2018-06-24  2018-06-25  2018-06-26  2018-06-27  2018-06-28  2018-06-29
```

---

Conditional formatting custom formula:

```
=AND($A2<=C$1,$B2>=C$1)
```

Apply to:

```
C2:I
```

All of C2:I will be formatted according to the dates in A2:B.